# Cambiar img en responsive wordpress

Tags: wordpress, imagen, responsive

Estoy teniendo problemas con las `imagenes` que ocupan todo un `div` `1080px`, a pasarlas a `responsive` quiero que estas ocupen mas de largo que de ancho obviamente recortando la foto por los laterales pero no consigo hacerlo, como mucho estirando la foto y eso queda bastante mal, alguna solución?

[html del wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al1Hd.png)

[image: css de la imagen]

y el div del padre tiene display: block

como podeis observar es wordpress, me dijeron durante el fin de semana que se podria conseguir poniendo la imagen como background

Comment: Podrías intentar usar los media querys de css, eso te ayudará.

Comment: @Carlos puedes agregar como estas haciendo el código para visualizar en que estas fallando y poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que la imagen no te reescale, como entiendo que te está ocurriendo, tienes la opción de usar la propiedad CSS "overflow: hidden".

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img src="url_de_tu_imagen" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 500px
}
```

Este código, lo que haría sería que al mostrarse la imagen en un dispositivo más pequeño, al tenerla con un tamaño fijo y a su contenedor con la propiedad mencionada, evitarías ese reescalado y el sobrante (que sin el overflow:hidden se saldría de su caja) desaparecería.

No sé si esto es lo que buscabas. Si no fuese así te agradecería que aportases más información.

Un saludo ^^

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no me ha funcionado por el momento, espero sacar la solucion durante el dia de hoy, en cuanto la saque pondre la respuesta por si le puede ayudar a otro usuario

Comment: Si cuelgas el código HTML y concretas un poco más lo que deseas conseguir, tal vez pueda darte una mejor solución.

EDIT: Acabo de ver que lo tienes subido, le echo un vistazo.

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el HTML del section cuyo comportamiento deseas conseguir? Lo que has colgado es una imagen en la que el código sale cortado.

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido poniendo la imagen en background en cover y centrado, asi según se va haciendo responsive se va comiendo la foto poco a poco por los lados y en responsive se ve mas largo que ancho. Gracias por la ayuda